# NSString drawInRect:withAttributes: not correctly centered when using NSKernAttributeName

Tags: ios, nsstring, core-graphics, text-alignment, kerning

When I use `drawInRect:withAttributes:` and pass in both a paragraph style with `NSTextAlignmentCenter` and a non-zero value for `NSKernAttributeName`, the string does not get centered correctly. Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behavior? Is there a workaround?

Screenshot:

[image]

You can clearly see that top text is not centered correctly.

My demo code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
    [self drawString:@"88" inRect:rect font:font textColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- (void)drawString:(NSString *)text
            inRect:(CGRect)contextRect
              font:(UIFont *)font
         textColor:(UIColor *)textColor
{
    CGFloat fontHeight = font.lineHeight;
    CGFloat yOffset = floorf((contextRect.size.height - fontHeight) / 2.0) + contextRect.origin.y;

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(contextRect.origin.x, yOffset, contextRect.size.width, fontHeight);

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    [text drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:@{NSKernAttributeName: @(self.kerning),
                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
                                            NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle}];
}
```

Thanks!

**Update**, thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741850/nsstring-drawinrectwithattributes-not-correctly-centered-when-using-nskernattr?noredirect=1#comment36498149_23741850), I added `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]` to the attributes and got the following result:

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering, if you add to the draw `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName`, it's "centered" in it.

Comment: Good observation, that's true! But that's even a different bug then: Because the background color is not applied to the whole text.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot with that (with the 2 cases)? It was just a guess. But I figured that could help. I often provide a flashy background color to some UI elements to check their frames, so I just suggest the same here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The kerning must be applied only to the *first* character of each kerning pair.
If you want to display a string with kerning between all `n` characters then the kerning
attribute must be set for the first `n-1` characters.

Instead of:

```
[text drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:@{NSKernAttributeName: @(self.kerning),
                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
                                        NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle}];
```

you have to create an *attributed string* so that you can set the kerning attribute
for a specific range instead of the entire string:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *as = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                 initWithString:text
                                 attributes:@{
                                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
                                              NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle}];
[as addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
           value:@(self.kerning)
           range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length] - 1)];

[as drawInRect:textRect];
```

Here the result for the string "1234" and kerning -4.0:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That is perfect! I was also looking for a "tracking" instead of a "kerning" attribute, but I didn't find one.

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug: What do you mean by "tracking"?

Comment: Kerning is for specific letter pairs, tracking is more general: http://www.graphics.com/article-old/design-fundamentals-kerning-and-tracking