# How do I avoid this while changing the character spacing of UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to change the character spacing of uitextview. However it changes whole appearance.
Screenshots:

**Before adding the code**

[image: Before adding the code]

**After adding the code**

[image: After adding the code]

Code (as extension):

```
extension UITextView {

    func addCharacterSpacing(kernValue: Double = 1.15) {
        if let textValue = text, textValue.count > 0 {
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textValue)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: kernValue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length - 1))
            attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535901/ios-8-change-character-spacing-on-uilabel-within-interface-builder

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `NSMutableAttributedString`, so you should customize it fully in the same way with `paragraph style` and `fonts` for it or `any other settings`.

From the screenshots I see a problem with paragraph style, setup it manually to the `textView`:

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .center

textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
     string: "string",
     attributes: [.paragraphStyle: paragraph])
```

Comment: Thank you but the font still is smaller than it should be.

Comment: @AnnoThra what about: `let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 18.0)!]` and add it too the `attributes`. Please check example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/1278744